# Change password in Rescue mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, password

I using ubuntu 21 with two nvme raid
How i can change root passwd in rescue mode?
[lsblk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NqRe.png)
[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI9jJ.png)

Comment: What kind of raid? hardware? pseudo-hardware? mdraid?

Answer (score -1):

Changing Your Root Password in Ubuntu.

Step 1: Open a Terminal Window

Right-click the desktop, then left-click Open in terminal.

Alternately, you can click Menu > Applications > Accessories > Terminal.

Step 2: Change Your Root Password

In the terminal window, type the following:

```
sudo passwd root
```

The system will prompt you to enter your password – this is the same password you use to log in to the system.

Next, the system will prompt you to enter a new password. Do so, and then re-enter it exactly the same when the system prompts you to retype the password. This double-entry confirms that you have typed the password correctly.

For more information go through this [documentation](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-change-root-password-linux). you will get the answers.

Comment: Eh, not if they are in rescue mode.